# How many entries are in a vtable for an abstract virtual function?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, vtable, vptr

I read that an abstract class can still have a table. But I'm confused on how many entries it would have in its vtable. For example, if my abstract class was:

```
class Circle(){
    virtual void draw() = 0;
}
```

then how many entries would be in its vtable? Also, am I correct in saying that this abstract class has 1 entry in its vtable? Thanks for any help.

```
class Circle(){
    virtual double a{ return 0.0; }
    virtual void draw() = 0;
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking: the concrete vtable for the concrete instances of the abstract class, or the layout of the vtable?

Comment: Each vtable needs entries to support things like `typeid` in addition to virtual function calls.

Comment: BTW, there are no " abstract virtual functions", only pure virtual functions and abstract classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every virtual function can be overridden. The compiler has to build in some mechanism to dynamically dispatch calls to each virtual function so that the code calls the right overriding version, which depends on the actual type of the object. That mechanism is typically a vtable, and there has to be one entry for each virtual function. So the first example would have one entry, and the second would have two. Note that marking a function as pure virtual does not affect this; it still has to be dynamically dispatched.

Comment: @bolov -- you're asking very implementation-specific questions. From the perspective of the language definition, none of this matters, as long as the program does what the standard says it's supposed to do. It's entirely up to the compiler to figure out how to handle the dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @bolov -- yes, I said that in my answer: "That mechanism **is typically** a vtable". To answer your question directly: the compiler **could** generate 42 entries in the vtable for the destructor. It **could** also generate 42 entries in the vtable  for any other virtual function, or for any non-virtual function, or for any data members, or for anything else the compiler writer feels like.

Comment: You are forgetting the needs of RTTI.

Answer (score 4):

First, vtables are an implementation detail. As long as you're not doing really weird things, you should ignore their existence.

Second, even though all compilers use vtables to implement virtual dispatch, there are differences in how they do it. For some, a vtable entry is just a function pointer; for others, it's a pointer an an offset. Some compilers have one entry for a virtual destructor, some have two, or even more. And some add a new entry for a covariantly overriden function, while others might not.

The bottom line is that you shouldn't, in general, worry about this issue. If you are interested in implementation details, you could for example read the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/), which is what Linux compilers generally follow.

Comment: Surely only Linux compilers for Itanic?  The x86, x64, and ARM ABIs will be rather different.

Comment: @MartinBonner No, the Itanium C++ ABI forms the basis (with only minor platform-specific differences) of the ABI that all Linux compilers now follow.

Answer (score 2):

Well, vtables are an implementation-detail, though an ubiquitous one.

As neither `Circle`'s ctor-body nor dtor-body calls any of its functions, especially none calling virtual ones, and it is abstract due to the pure virtual function, `Circle`'s vtable is never used, if it is in fact even created.

Anyway, the theoretical vtable needs at least one entry for the [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) and any other support for `dynamic_cast`, one for each virtual function, and if the dtor is virtual, two for that (one just for the dtor, one for dtor + deallocation with `delete`).

Which comes to at least 3 entries (2 virtual functions + RTTI) for your second example.

Comment: Other answers suggest the number of slots for virtual destructors varies between compilers.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Well, actually the other answers are facetious when they suggest that. And I only gave the minimum number to fulfill requirements.